# c# How to read and write from multiline textBox line by line?

Tags: c#, string, text, textbox, line

I have a simple program it has a function to read a line  from multiline textBox when i press a button
what i made to do that is this code :

```
TextReader read = new System.IO.StringReader(textBox1.Text);
int rows = 100;

string[] text1 = new string[rows];
for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++)
{
    text1[r] = read.ReadLine();
}
```

so when click button1 it the code will be like this:

```
textBox2=text1[1];
```

[1] mean the first line     How can i do it automaticaly by one click ?
  or  with one click  the first line to textBox2
the second to textBox3  .....ect..

plz i want the code and where i should put it    ^_^

or if there is another way to do that

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The property [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) is there for you

```
if(textBox1.Lines.Length > 0)
    textBox2.Text=textBox1.Lines[0];
```

or, put your textboxes ordered in a temporary array and loop on them (of course we should always check the number of lines present in textBox1)

```
TextBox[] text = new TextBox[] {textBox2, textBox3, textBox4};
if(textBox.Lines.Length >= 3)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
       text[x] = textBox1.Lines[x];
}
```

Comment: ...and TextBox.Lines is a string[], so it is an exact replacement for the text1 variable in the original post.

Comment: a want to do a loop for [1] [2] [3] string   how can i do it

Comment: Note: Textbox.lines is only available for Windows Forms (not webforms)

Answer (score 10):

Simple programming read and write a one-by-one line from multiline textBox in C#

Write line one-by-one:

```
textbox1.AppendText("11111111+");
textbox1.AppendText("\r\n222222222");
textbox1.AppendText("\r\n333333333");
textbox1.AppendText("\r\n444444444");
textbox1.AppendText("\r\n555555555");
```

Read line one-by-one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textbox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    textbox2.Text += textbox1.Lines[i] + "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet for reading comma separated and newline separated values from multiline textbox -

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(txtBoxId.Text)))
        {
            string IdOrder = Convert.ToString(txtBoxId.Text.Trim());

            //replacing "enter" i.e. "\n" by ","
            string temp = IdOrder.Replace("\r\n", ",");            

            string[] ArrIdOrders = Regex.Split(temp, ",");

            for (int i = 0; i < ArrIdOrders.Length; i++)
            {
              //your code
            }
         }
```

I Hope this would help you.